# Refresh/restart a javascript on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mixitup

I use the ["mixitup"-script](https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/) and I want to refresh/restart only this script, not the whole page, by pressing a button.

```
$(function(){
  $('.container').mixItUp();
});
```

Is that possible?

[My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gt8wmd23/)

Comment: Why do you want to refresh? is there new content? If you check the mixItUp docs there is a way to destroy the functionality and then you can simply call `$('.container').mixItUp()` again, i doubt this is the best way to solve the issue though

Comment: I have to use an other way to reset my filters for mixitup, but if I reset my filters they doesn´t refresh the content, so I want to integrate a refresh/restart.

Comment: I don't get what u want to refresh? 
e.g.: do you want to "mix" the 8 squares, switch them from position? or do I get you wrong?

Comment: I am testing the "destroy"-method at the moment

Comment: Ok, the "destroy"-method works for me - thx for help!